# How to find out how many textures an object has with python?

Tags: python, scripting

For example, I have multiple objects with multiple textures attached to their materials. How to print out for each object in the scene the number of textures it has?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that prints out all objects of type `'MESH'` and the number of textures. It also provides details of the textures and under which material they reside.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type != 'MESH':
        continue
    texture_count = 0
    textures = ''
    for mat_slot in obj.material_slots:
        mat = mat_slot.material
        if not mat:
            continue
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            if node.type.startswith('TEX_'):
                textures += '\t' + mat_slot.name + ": " + node.type + " (linked=" + str(any(link.is_linked for link in node.outputs)) + ')\n'
                texture_count += 1
    print(f"{obj.name} ===> {texture_count}")
    print(f"{textures}")
```

Example Output:

[image]